# Delphi cxDBPivotGrid - фильтр по итоговой колонке (Grand Total)

Tags: delphi

Можно ли в Delphi cxDBPivotGrid фильтровать данные в итоговой колонке? Как обратиться к итоговой колонке, чтобы написать фильтр самостоятельно?
Спасибо.

Comment: Фильтровать GrandTotal скорее всего не получится. Опишите задачу попдробнее. Возможно есть другие варианты для ее решения.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: Есть возможность фильтра по полям строк, колонок, данных. А надо отфильтровать итоговый подсчет (например, сумма значений поля Количество>100).

Comment: Итоговое поле "Grand Total" нигде явно не описан, обратиться к нему получается только:cxDBPivotGrid.ViewData.CellsAsText[0, cxDBPivotGrid.ViewData.ColumnCount-1] - т.е последняя колонка (может быть и первой). Как сделать фильтр?

Comment: Усть возможность вкл/выкл фильтра по колонке: cxDBPivotGrid.Fields[cxDBPivotGrid.ViewData.ColumnCount-1].Filter:=false; А как записать текст в фильтр?

Comment: Получается записать текст в префильтр, но не могу задать имя итоговой колонки (т.к. её нет в списке полей):

Comment: DataController.Filter.Active:=false; DataController.Filter.Root.Clear; DataController.Filter.Root.AddItem(cxDBPivotGridTableView1Field1,foLess,1300,'1300');